# Error when trying to access variable in function - using [[ ]]

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function to print by a grouping variable. It works when I essentially rename the id variable to the argument name, but I'd like to do it by using the variable name as an argument instead. I have tried using [[ ]] but I'm obviously still doing something wrong.

I have added the output that the first function gives and I basically want to emulate that with the second function. I have now also tried [["id"]], but need to work out why it's skipping the if statement.

```
# Load data
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")

# Create function
print_groups <- function(df, index1, index2) {
  ids_all <-  unique(df$id)
  ids_range <- ids_all[index1:index2]
  if (index1 <= length(ids_all) & index2 <= length(ids_all)) {
    for (id in ids_range) {
      temp <- df[df$id %in% id,]
      print(by(temp, temp$id, identity)[id])
      cat("----------------------------\n\n")
    }
  } else {
    print("There aren't that many groups in your dataset")
  }
}
# Get data ready to use with function
sleepstudy$id <- sleepstudy$Subject   # substitute id variable name here
> print_groups(sleepstudy, 1, 3)        # THIS WORKS
$`308`
   Reaction Days Subject  id
1  249.5600    0     308 308
2  258.7047    1     308 308
3  250.8006    2     308 308
4  321.4398    3     308 308
5  356.8519    4     308 308
6  414.6901    5     308 308
7  382.2038    6     308 308
8  290.1486    7     308 308
9  430.5853    8     308 308
10 466.3535    9     308 308

----------------------------

$`309`
   Reaction Days Subject  id
11 222.7339    0     309 309
12 205.2658    1     309 309
13 202.9778    2     309 309
14 204.7070    3     309 309
15 207.7161    4     309 309
16 215.9618    5     309 309
17 213.6303    6     309 309
18 217.7272    7     309 309
19 224.2957    8     309 309
20 237.3142    9     309 309

----------------------------

$`310`
   Reaction Days Subject  id
21 199.0539    0     310 310
22 194.3322    1     310 310
23 234.3200    2     310 310
24 232.8416    3     310 310
25 229.3074    4     310 310
26 220.4579    5     310 310
27 235.4208    6     310 310
28 255.7511    7     310 310
29 261.0125    8     310 310
30 247.5153    9     310 310

----------------------------

# Now include id variable as a function argument

rm(list = ls())
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")

# Now include id variable as a function argument
print_groups <- function(df, id, index1, index2) {
  ids_all <-  unique(df[["id"]])
  ids_range <- ids_all[index1:index2]
  if (index1 <= length(ids_all) & index2 <= length(ids_all)) {
    for (id in ids_range) {
      temp <- df[df[["id"]] %in% id,]
      print(by(temp, temp$id, identity)[id])
      cat("----------------------------\n\n")
    }
  } else {
    print("There aren't that many groups in your dataset")
  }
}
print_groups(sleepstudy, Subject, 1, 3) # THIS DOESN'T WORK
[1] "There aren't that many groups in your dataset"
```

Comment: Could you please provide sample dataset and desired output?

Comment: If `df$id` works, then it's the column name and you have to quote it, `df[["id"]]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas `df[["id"]` accesses a column named `id`. OP wants to access a column given by the formal argument `id`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, the function doesn't have an argument `id`, what it does have is an extraction `df$id`. In fact twice, one is the 1st function instruction `ids_all <-  unique(df$id)` and the 2nd is the first `for` loop instruction. So the column *is* named `"id"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas The second function does (scroll down in the code).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using lazy evaluation.

```
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
# Load data
data("sleepstudy")

print_groups <- function(df, id, index1, index2) {
  ids_all <-  unique(eval(substitute(id), df))
  ids_range <- ids_all[index1:index2]
  if (index1 <= length(ids_all) & index2 <= length(ids_all)) {
    for (id2 in ids_range) {
      print(df[eval(substitute(id), df) %in% id2,])
      cat("----------------------------\n\n")
    }
  } else {
    print("There aren't that many groups in your dataset")
  }
}

# Use function
print_groups(sleepstudy, Subject, 18, 18)
```

Comment: FYI, `rm(list = ls())` is an anti-pattern. If you want to have a clean session, restart your R session instead.